# Fedora 23 - can't re-login after logout

Tags: login, gnome3, cinnamon, gdm, logout

After I logout I can't login back. I type the password but just got a blink, then the login screen is back again without error messages. I have to reboot to login again. Besides, even the Nautilus that's shipped with Fedora, keeps crashing over and over. I suspect it's something related do desktop manager.
I'm using Cinnamon now, but even with Gnome 3 the error happens.

Some tips about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having this same problem, and only since upgrading to Fedora 23:

I log out and when I try to log back in, I get sent back to the login screen.

<strike>I have been looking for a relevant bug report but can't find one (and since I do have a Fedora account, I might just start one).</strike>

There is a Fedora bug report for this issue:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1266587

My workaround is:

- After logging out, go to a virtual console with `ctrl-alt-F2`
- Log in at the console. Then log out.
- Go back to GDM with `ctrl-alt-F1`
- Log in as normal. It will now work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's "only" the desktop, you can switch to a virtual console, e.g., by pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to the second virtual console.  The login prompt there will work, provided your password is correct (and of course, assuming that your shell is working properly).

X normally runs on virtual console 7.  You can switch back to the GUI login using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.  Per comment, *Fedora23* runs on `tty`, so you "should" be able to switch back using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

Once you are logged in, you can troubleshoot your system, e.g., checking logs for the problem, reinstalling suspect packages, etc.

Further reading:

- [7. Console switching](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html) (The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO)
- [Switching Between GUI and Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292069/switching-between-gui-and-terminal/292076)

Comment: Fedora 23 runs your X session directly in `tty1` (i.e., the first virtual terminal on your physical screen). It starts new sessions in the next virtual terminals as asked only.

Comment: Interesting (I had not thought to look).  But on my Fedora23 VM, I can switch to tty2 without problem.  Switching back (to tty1), I get a prompt for authenticating with the pc/sc daemon (which works for me).  OP may have problems in any case, but there's not enough information as yet.

Comment: After waiting a few seconds (about 20s), I can login back. Locking the screen don't bring me that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of Fedora 25.

Well the workaround that I use is simple. Use a second virtual terminal. When I see that I cannot log back in I simply use `ctrl + alt + f2`, then login at the command prompt and then type `startx`. This bring me back to the graphical desktop, but using a second virtual terminal, it seems that for now the first terminal is inaccessible after logging out. The only thing to fix it is a restart.

Comment: Can you explain how this differs from the already present answers?

Comment: @StephenRauch None of the other answers mention of starting the Graphical Desktop environment using `startx`